# Render Problem : java.lang.NullPointerException while creating TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am getting a render problem while creating a tab layout. Refreshing the layout is also not working.can't see the preview of the design due to this.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor = "@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/Chatsid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chats" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/Callid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calls" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Stack trace:

java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)   at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1631)   at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:874)   at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3965)   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:216)   at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.setTextAppearance(MaterialTextView.java:106)   at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3954)   at androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:289)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.updateTab(TabLayout.java:2772)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2801)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2713)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1673)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:956)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:824)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1730)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1720)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1131)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)

Edit:-

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TabLayout"
        tools:targetApi="33">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.tablayout'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tablayout"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: What version of material library are you using?

Comment: in your xml preview window, try selecting different theme.

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart I am using 1.8.0.

Comment: @WSAyan I tried different themes in the XML preview window, but the issue is still there.

Comment: I found this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75588913/7454336
Not sure if it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade the material library to:
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

This downgrade worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).